# How can the PL/SQL grammar included with ANTLR4 be tested?

Tags: java, oracle, parsing, plsql, antlr4

I'm just getting started using ANTLR, and want to try test parsing some simple PL/SQL statements using the [plsql.g4](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/plsql) grammar. I am following the format used in [Getting Started with ANTLR v4](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/getting-started.md).

The following commands execute without issue:

```
antlr4 plsql.g4
java org.antlr.v4.Tool plsql.g4
javac plsql*.java
```

In the getting started example, they run the following command:

```
grun Hello r -tree
```

Where 'Hello' is the name of the grammar and 'r' is one of its production rules. The grammar indicates that the 'sql_script' production rule consists of zero or more unit statements or sqlplus commands followed by the end of the input stream:

```
sql_script
    : (unit_statement | sql_plus_command)* EOF
    ;
```

So I am trying to invoke the PL/SQL parser like so:

```
grun plsql sql_script -tree
```

But I get the following error:

```
Can't load plsql as lexer or parser
```

What is the correct way to invoke the parser for this grammar to generate a parse tree for a simple PL/SQL statement? I am using JDK 8 on a Windows machine. Here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZ6Ca.jpg) showing the contents of my terminal window.

Comment: I executed all the commands as you did and everything works! I manage to reproduce error when I deleted `plsqlLexer.class` file. Are you sure you execute the `grun plsql sql_script -tree` command in the directory where `plsqlLexer.class` and `plsqlParser$*.class` files are present?

Comment: Yes. Here is a [screenshot](http://imgur.com/9EIfkuh) showing the contents of my terminal window.

Comment: On the screenshot : why all of the `plsqlParser$*.class` files listed with `ls` command are enclosed with single quotation marks `'`?

Comment: @Quepas I'm not sure. I think it's just a quirk of Windows command prompt. If I use the same command in PowerShell, it displays them without the single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

The JVM is the culprit. It does not automatically check the working directory first before checking the system-wide %CLASSPATH% environment variable if it exists. Adding a '.' to the beginning of the %CLASSPATH% environment variable will fix the problem and allow the command to work as intended. Refer to this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmwdD.jpg) of the Edit Environment Variable tool in Windows 10 to see how it should look.

This tool can be accessed through Control Panel -> System and Security -> System, click on the item to the left that says "Advanced system settings", and then click on the button labeled "Environment Variables". Selecting a variable and then clicking the "Edit..." button will bring up the tool in the screenshot.

Comment: There was no such change. I've been using Java since 1997 and it has always worked like this. `.` is the default CLASSPATH if you don't have one at all, but it was never automatically pretended if there was one.

Comment: @EJP My understanding is that the behavior is JVM implementation specific. For example, I don't recall OpenJDK working that way.

Comment: @EJP I have changed the wording of the answer so as not to place blame on a change in behavior, and instead simply described the current behavior. Either way, this is the correct answer; as the person who asked the question, I can confirm that this was the solution to the problem. I'd appreciate it if you retracted your downvote.